# How do I visualize inputtext on the keyboard (tablet)?

Tags: javascript, android, html, tablet

I am trying to create a webpage that works for tablets correctly, and some input-windows are under the keyboard when it's shown. My designer had an idea of adding the users input on the keyboard, something like [this](https://gyazo.com/6946f24d42f09e3ff3988b9f790695d7).

Not that it has to be password like, it was the only example I could find from a quick google search, but is there a way to implement this in the web-app? Or is this just based on whan operating system the user is running, eg. if Android has it in some version it would automatically work like my description?

Something I thought might be a workaround would be to temporarly add a textinput window at `bottom: 0px;` dynamic to the new window-size after the keyboard is visible..

Anything anyone have tried?